# Result getting jammed in a web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF web service that uses a legacy exe file. Following is the architecture that i'm using.

[image]

Now i get a big problem. This exe can response to only one request at a time. So i need to run it synchronously by web service.

Unfortunately the application that uses this web service can only send Asynchronous requests. and i don't have permission to change it.

Due to this problem log file get jammed and results are not clear.

can i solve this from web service side ? any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by one at a time? Per machine? Per user? Per executable name?

Comment: You can create worker which collects reqests and process it one by one. So WebService calls worker instead cmd. Or you can move functionality from cmd to your worker or WebService

Comment: As BWA said, this seems to call for some kind of message queue system.

Answer (score 3):

WCF services can be configured with a ConcurrencyMode, which you can set to Single and this allows a single thread only.

From the docs:

> Each instance context is allowed to have a maximum of one thread
>   processing messages in the instance context at a time. Other threads
>   wishing to use the same instance context must block until the original
>   thread exits the instance context.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can you callback here :)

[How to: Implement an Asynchronous Web Service Client Using the Callback Technique](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyd0d1e5(v=vs.80).aspx)